# How to pass a table as argtype to postgres function?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

```
create table test_tbl (id int, name character varying(10));

insert test_tbl values(1,'A');
insert test_tbl values(2,'B');
insert test_tbl values(3,'C');
insert test_tbl values(4,'D');
insert test_tbl values(5,'F');
```

Now i want to pass this table as a input argtype to function.

```
create function myfn (in tbl (how to define the table input))
as 
return set of <some type>
begin 
 return query AS
 select concat(id,name)  
 from test_tbl 
 where id in (select id from in_tbl);

end;
```

How to declare table type input argument? 
How to call this function with table input?

```
select * from myfn(<pass the table - test_tbl>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the type `regclass` and build a dynamic query

```
create or replace function myfn (in tbl regclass)

returns TABLE(id INT)
as  $$
begin 

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('select id 
 from test 
 where id in (select id from %s)',tbl);

end 
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and you call it using

```
select * from myfn('mytablename');
```